# Side by side programs on at the same time

Tags: screen

With the new update when you have half the screen with a program open and then click to start a new program it makes the previously open program disappear.  Anyway to disable this new feature?  Have to move the window to my other monitor and then back as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inbuilt keyboard shortcuts in 18.04 to snap windows to either the left or right of the screen. If a program is snapped to the left of the screen, opening a new program will appear over the top of it but as the focus is on the new window opened, you can then snap it to the right.

The shortcuts are as follows:

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> = snap application to left edge of screen

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> = snap application to right edge of screen

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> = maximise the application window (left or right)

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> = bring application window back to normal self.

Click the application header to change focus from one window to the other as per normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I quick restart and it stopped doing it....Was weird b/c it looked like a sleek new way to move b/w programs but I couldn't find a way to opt out... Thanks again!